# Looking for creative way to sort query results based on column value resembling filepath

Tags: sql-server

Long story short, I have these file paths that are meaningful to the application that I am building. This table exists in the database that I could possibly use to better sort the data before it is used in the program. I am pulling the data from the SQL database, and I am using a sproc to pull the data into the app. Lets call the column a file path, but its not. Its like a hierarchy of sorts. Any way an example of the data that I have is the following.

| PK | FileName | Filepath |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | FileName | Folder1 > Foldera > FileName |
|  | FileName | Folder2 > Folderb > FileName |

With that, I need to order the results to group like levels around the hierarchy.

So what I mean is results like the following:

```
File1
File1 >Foldera
File1 > Foldera > file
File2> 
File2> Folderb
File2> Folderb > file
```

And so on and so forth. so to break it out a bit further, I would like to order by them like this if the value is documented using the following placeholders:

| FileName | Filepath |
| --- | --- |
| FileName | String1 > String2 > String3 |

```
select *
from table 
order by string1 asc, string2 asc, string3 asc
```

I have messed around with len, replace, charindex to pull out the values in between the greater than symbol, but I feel like that is going to be pretty performance costly to do that across thousands of potential rows. I have also tested with string_split which would be stellar, but that wont work for ordering all of the rows given it breaks them into a table valued object, not a row of data like I wish it was. Perhaps I am just missing a fundamental concept of the string_split function.

Here is the general idea behind using all those substring functions, but this would only pull string1. SO it would turn into a bunch of nested statements like this, but since I dont know how deep it goes, as in how many tiers there are in the path, I can't find these in absolute terms.

```
select replace(SUBSTRING(filepath, 1, CHARINDEX( '.', filepath)), '>', '')
```

What I mean by how many tiers there are, I mean there could be 7 'tiers' or strings to the right or left of the greater than symbols, so if I used something like the above, it would have to be dynamic, and that is where the performance issues come in, I think.

This isnt a show stopper, because I have them ordered by length of the filepath which works fine for what its used for, but it could be better. I am open to hearing solutions in C# as well, if that would help. I can pass them into a list or something if that is easier. I would like to do it on the SQL side within a sproc, but if thats not possible, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like simple order by clause do exactly what you asking for. Except if you want your filepath being separeted on different columns by ">" symbol.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR89g.png)

Comment: Ha! Wonderful, I assumed these were system generated, but they have irregular spaces entered in them which was skewing my reality vs expectations. I just threw a replace on there for ' ', and they return exactly as I expect. Thank you so much for getting me there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).